# Problema al acceder al atributo email en modelo de usuario Django con AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente modelo simple que extiende de **AbstracUser** y estoy aplicando que para el cambio de contraseña se neesita aceptar una confirmación por mail y al momento de acceder al email del usuario filtrado por el mismo email me da el siguiente error

> Cannot access member "email" for type "AbstractBaseUser"
> Member "email" is unknown

Si estoy usando **AbstractUser** y no **AbstractBaseUser**. Por qué me está dando este error?

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class UserBase(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=122, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=122)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuario'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
# views.py
@user_not_authenticated
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordResetFormCust(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_user = get_user_model().objects.filter(Q(email=user_email)).first()
            if associated_user:
                subject = "Password Reset request"
                message = render_to_string("template_reset_password.html", {
                    'user': associated_user,
                    'domain': get_current_site(request).domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(associated_user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(associated_user),
                    "protocol": 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'
                })
                email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[associated_user.email]) 
    

# !!! En la línea anterior está el error, en 'associated_user.email'

                if email.send():
                    messages.success(request,
                        """
                        <h2>Password reset sent</h2><hr>
                        <p>
                            We've emailed you instructions for setting your password, if an account exists with the email you entered. 
                            You should receive them shortly.<br>If you don't receive an email, please make sure you've entered the address 
                            you registered with, and check your spam folder.
                        </p>
                        """
                    )
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Problem sending reset password email, <b>SERVER PROBLEM</b>")

            return redirect('homepage')

        for key, error in list(form.errors.items()):
            if key == 'captcha' and error[0] == 'This field is required.':
                messages.error(request, "You must pass the reCAPTCHA test")
                continue
```